# How to reference a global variable in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access VBA I know you can reference an object by using a string: `Me("string")`. I want to reference a global variable in a function using a string, thus allowing me to use the function for different states.

e.g. I have `invoiceBtn` and `infoBtn` buttons, I want to call the same function but using different variables. There are global variables `infoBool` and `invoiceBool`

```
Private Sub infoBtn_Click()
  functionName("info")
End Sub

Private Sub invoiceBtn_Click()
  functionName("invoice")
End Sub
```

in the function:

```
public infoBool As Boolean
public invoiceBool As Boolean

public Function functionName(typeString As String)
  Me(typeString & "Bool") = false
  Me(typeString & "Btn").visible = false
End Function
```

The first Me() doesn't compile, the second Me() does, is there a way to obtain a reference to a variable using a string?

edited: I hope it is clear enough now. This is just example code, not used in my program.

Comment: VBA variables cannot be dynamically constructed.

Comment: Not sure why you get the compile issue on the Call line. Type is a reserved word and should not use reserved words as names for anything.

Comment: For this type of thing you'd typically use a Dictionary, but your example code isn't really enough to go on...

Comment: The compile error is probably because you are calling a function and function must be on the right side of an expression: `x = functionName("invoice")`. Make the function a sub then the Call should compile. But still can't dynamically construct VBA variables.

Comment: @June7 #FunFacts: `Type` is a perfectly legal UDT member name. Otherwise yeah, using it is kind of asking for trouble. That said, VBA doesn't care if you use a function as a sub (and thus discard the returned value) - people do that all the time with the `MsgBox` function...

Comment: `Me(...)` brings to mind the form's controls collection which can be referenced by the control's name e.g. `Me.Controls("ContolName")`?

Comment: You'll have to [edit] your question to clarify what you're trying to achieve and in what context, otherwise it's pretty much impossible to give you a definitive answer. If `invoiceBool` is a global variable, then `invoiceBool` all by itself wouldn't be a legal instruction *anyway* - what's `Me(type & "Bool")` trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mat'sMug, sure, can use a function but still must be in an expression, not with the Call method. So change one or the other procedure.

Comment: `Call MsgBox("What about this?")` is perfectly legal. `Sub` or `Function` makes no difference, `Call` doesn't care at all. The main problem is that `Me(type & "Bool")` is not an instruction - *even if it were a valid way to refer to a variable*. When you access a variable, it's either to read it, or to assign it. Treating it as an instruction isn't going to compile.

Comment: Well, that is confusing! I am sure I received error messages in past when trying Call with a function. I am now re-educated.

Comment: @June7 rule of thumb, `Call` is obsolete and useless ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases you can try to use `Eval` function for evaluating functions, but it doesn't work with variables.

You can use collection for storing values or references to objects, so in this case your code will look like

```
Public col As Collection

Public Function functionName(typeString As String)
  'for scalar data types element should be replaced, cannot change value
  col.Remove typeString & "Bool"
  col.Add False, typeString & "Bool"

  'object references can be used directly
  col(typeString & "Btn").Visible = False
End Function
```

Before using this you should add all desired values or object references

```
Set col = New Collection

col.Add True, "infoBool"
col.Add Me.InfoBtn, Me.InfoBtn.Name
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. Seems a bit tedious to first add all references to objects to this collection, is it common practice to leave the objects like in my example, and store the variables in a collection?

Comment: It depends on complexity, but in any case try to avoid using global variables, use classes or functions with static variables